# Protractor Using Xpath to find grand child of grandparent Not Working

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to find an element using Protractor. There are many drop downs on a page and I need to find the right one. The only way I can see of doing this is to find the grandparent of the item and then look at another grandchild which contains the label.

This works but returns many items:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-isolate-scope']
```

I am trying then to tack on the additional parts to find the grandparent and then a child "a" tag and then a child "span" which contains the text I need to match against.

So this is not working:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-isolate-scope']//..//a/span[.='Country']"));
```

Anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the grandparent of the context node you could use `../..`. Then to find a child node, you can use just the child axis. So, in your question, if the `a` element is a child of the grandparent of `span`, the xpath should be something like:

`//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-isolate-scope']/../../a`

And, to find its child `span` with value `Country`:
`//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-isolate-scope']/../../a/span[.='Country']`